# How to install a latex package in MacOS TeXLive?

Tags: packages, installing, texlive, macports, cyrillic

I just downloaded `cyrillic` package into a temp directory and executed:

```
sudo latex cyrlatex.ins
```

It works, but it produces a few dozen files in the same directory. How to place them into my TeXLive installation directory? Or let's put it this way - how to install a package into TeXLive on Mac OS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should extract the package into `~/texmf/tex/latex/$PACKAGENAME` and run latex from that folder. After that you should run `texhash` or `mktexlsr` from your home folder

Comment: I've placed it into `/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/cyrillic` (I have TeXLive installation by macports), looks like it's ok

Comment: I don't think you need the ls-R files for things in `~/texmf` so there shouldn't be any need to run `mktexlsr`.

Comment: FWIW, to install for a single user on OS X, you can place those files in the users ~/Library/texmf/latex/$PACKAGENAME directory.  I'm not sure if this is the more "proper" method for OS X compared to using just the ~/texmf/tex... structure that is typical on other *nix systems.

Comment: Just for documentation, in my case it is `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/$PACKAGENAME/`. The path in the home directory didn't work.

Answer (score 21):

if you have mactex 2009 or later (and why wouldn't you?!@?!) then use `tlmgr` from the command line to update and add packages:

`tlmgr install packagename`

and to update:
`tlmgr update --self`
then: `tlmgr update --all`

Comment: `sudo tlmgr`...

Comment: How can I install `tlmgr `?

Answer (score 10):

Instead of manually installing packages you could to install the package bundle which is suitable for your operating system. In your case you could install the bundle `texlive-lang-cyrillic` which contains the cyrillic package as well as needed fonts such as the LH fonts. You can read about the contents of macport packages here:

https://trac.macports.org/wiki/TeXLivePackages

Thus, you may execute at the command prompt:

```
sudo port install texlive-lang-cyrillic
```

as mentioned in [Using port install](http://guide.macports.org/#using.port.install).

Comment: There are many packages on CTAN which are not part of the package management system. ~/texmf is there so that users can install packages themself without messing with system folder.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the package from CTAN as a ZIP archive
2. Move the package archive to `~/Library/texmf/`
3. Unzip the archive. The archive will install its TeX files into `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/package_name` and its documentation files into `~/Library/texmf/doc/`. Those directories will be automatically created if they don't exist.

You do not need to run any commands to add the packages; if you have installed them to the correct path, TeX will automatically find them.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use TexLive Utility if you are using MacOSX. Get it from here:

http://amaxwell.github.io/tlutility/

This utility provides an interactive GUI where you can search for any package, see if it is already installed or not. In case not installed, you can install simply by right-clicking the package name and click install.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have come across a similar question with Basictex. Firstly, I can not find `texlive-lang-cyrillic` with `tlmgr`. Then I try to [download](https://packages.macports.org/texlive-lang-cyrillic/) and install it manually. But it still not work. At last, I did `sudo tlmgr install collection-langcyrillic` and it works.

I post this as an answer just in case someone comes across it again.