# Eforms on Mac OS X

Tags: texlive, acrotex

I am using Texclipse and TexLive. I just updated to TexLive 2011 and set my path

> /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/universal-darwin

however I don't have the eforms package that comes with acrotex. I have downloaded the acrotex bundle but I don't know how to install it. Anyone that could help me please?

By the way mac users do you recommend a different application than texlive?

Comment: Related question: [How to install a latex package in Mac OS texlive](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/how-to-install-a-latex-package-in-macos-texlive). Also, the path `/use/local/texlive...` should only effect the executables that get run, and not the packages that get loaded.

Comment: If you installed TeX Live using MacTeX, you should set your path to `/usr/texbin`.  Local additions go into `~/Library/texmf`. If you don't already have such a directory, you need to create one.  See [How to have local package override default package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/how-to-have-local-package-overide-default-package/8359#8359) for the basic structure.

Comment: Since you just upgraded, check you Preferences/TeX Distribution and make sure it is set to TeXLive-2011...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, using the MacTeX distribution of TeX Live, you should set any paths in your editor to point to `/Library/TeX/texbin`, *not* to the particular folder for the distribution.  This is so that subsequent updates will not require you to reset these paths.  `/Library/TeX/texbin` will always point to the binaries of the currently selected distribution.  (MacTeX allows you to have multiple years of TeXLive coexisting on the same machine, and selectable by a System Preferences control panel.)

The `acrotex` bundle requires installation via a `.ins` file. Unzip the `acrotex.zip` folder and put it in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/`.

You can do this part from the Finder by using the Go To Folder item in the Go menu and then entering `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex`. (If you are using OS 10.7 or later, you will *have* to do get to it this way, since the users Library is now hidden by default.)

If that folder is not found, you will need to create one by opening a terminal window and typing the following.  This creates a `tex/latex` folder to place the `.sty` and `.cls` files that you will generate plus an `acrotex` folder for the documentation.

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex
mkdir -p ~/Library/texmf/doc/tex/latex/acrotex
```

(Or you can create the folders in the finder, but the above is faster.)
Once you've copied the `acrotex` folder to `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex`,

do the following from a Terminal window:

```
cd ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/acrotex
latex acrotex.ins
```

This should generate all of the appropriate `.sty` and `.cls` files.

To make the documentation findable by `texdoc`, do the following:

```
cp doc/* ~/Library/texmf/doc/tex/latex/acrotex
```

Now everything should work.

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer, I appreciate it. I did exactly as you told me to do but my texclipse still cannot locate eforms.sty. How can I tell texclipse to look into the Library folder?

Comment: What is the result of `kpsewhich eforms.sty` from a new terminal window?  It should return `/Users/<yourusername>/Library/texmf/tex/latex/acrotex/eforms.sty`  Does it?

Comment: It doesn't return anything actually. Hmmmm so where is the problem you reckon?

Comment: That clearly means that you've not quite done everything right.  Just to be sure, what does `kpsewhich article.cls` return?  It should return `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls`.  If that works, try `touch ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/foo.sty` and then `kpsewhich foo.sty`. (This is just for testing.)

Comment: When I execute kpswewhich article.cls I get like yourself this /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls. However when i try kpswewhich foo.sty I get nothing once again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1455/discussion-between-alan-munn-and-dimitris)

Answer (score 1):

I’m using TL with Mac since version 2009 and it’s fine :-)

You can install additional packages in `<You>/Library/texmf/tex/latex` if you don’t find this path open a Terminal and type `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` (and press Enter) this gives you the right path, if this path doesn’t exist: create it ;-)

If you got a `sty` or `cls` file just copy it tho the mentioned folder. If you have an `ins` and a `dtx` file run `latex <filename>.ins` to create either `sty` or `cls` file and run `(pdf)latex <filename>.dtx` to create the manual.