# latexindent: Can't locate Log/Log4perl.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Log::Log4perl module)

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9, perl, latexindent

I have Strawberry Perl and MiKTeX v2.9 installed on Windows 10 with the `latexindent` package installed via the MiKTeX console.

However, running `latexindent.pl` in the command prompt results in the following error

> Can't locate Log/Log4perl.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
>   Log::Log4perl module) (@INC contains: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX
>   2.9/scripts/latexindent C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/lib) at C:/Program
>   Files/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/LogFile.pm line 22.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Program Files/MiKTeX
>   2.9/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/LogFile.pm line 22. Compilation failed in require at C:/Program Files/MiKTeX
>   2.9/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/Document.pm line 25. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Program Files/MiKTeX
>   2.9/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/Document.pm line 25. Compilation failed in require at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
>   2.9\scripts\latexindent\latexindent.pl line 27. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
>   2.9\scripts\latexindent\latexindent.pl line 27.

Additionally, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334511/2288) doesn't help in removing the error.
So, what is missing here?

Comment: Your Perl distribution is missing a module that's required by `latexindent`. The simplest way of installing a Perl module is using `cpan`. See [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865) and [Installing modules using Strawberry Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643939) on StackOverflow.

Comment: for Windows users, there is also `latexindent.exe` which doesn't need a `perl` installation. available from `ctan` https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexindent

Comment: to anyone reading this: I'd really like help in trying to communicate how to install `perl` modules and/or latexindent. the vast majority of questions on this site revolve around installation, which means that I clearly need to do more work in helping. please feel free to help me with this at `http://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/`

Comment: Log4Perl no longer required, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/587292/6621

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks to @Nicola's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445521/latexindent-cant-locate-log-log4perl-pm-in-inc-you-may-need-to-install-the-l?noredirect=1#comment1118650_445521), the error can be fixed as follows:

1. The missing module is `Log::Log4perl` as found in the first line of the error.
2. Open Win 10 start menu and search for `CPAN client`, then open it and run `install Log::Log4perl`. However, it may fail due to [the common bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=120926), which needs the installtion to be forced by running `force install Log::Log4perl` (from the **CPAN client**) or the other  **command prompt** commands given by the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37482732/2849383). In other words, for instance, the command  `cpan -f -i Log::Log4perl` must be run from the command prompt **NOT** the CPAN client.
3. Another module might be missing whose name can be identified as similarly done in the first step and installed the same way.

Comment: For the record, on my Debian, the additional missing modules where `Log::LogDispatch`, `Log::Dispatch::File`,  `YAML::Tiny` and `File::HomeDir`. You can install them all at once using `cpan Log::LogDispatch Log::Dispatch::File YAML::Tiny File::HomeDir`.

Comment: For MacOS, this also included `Unicode::GCString`, so the full installation solution was: `cpan -i Log::Log4perl Log::LogDispatch Log::Dispatch::File YAML::Tiny File::HomeDir Unicode::GCString`. This should be packaged to run at the end of `brew install mactex`.

Comment: @Clément cpan Log::Dispatch Log::Dispatch::File YAML::Tiny File::HomeDir

Comment: This solution finally got `latexindent` working after over two hours of trying to get it to work on my Mac. The perl installation didn't correctly update my PATH and I had to manually fix that. Then, as described here, I had to install the modules from inside `cpan` and none of the other documentation mentions that. Pretty frustrating experience. I hope I can get `latexindent` working on my MacBook Pro without the hassle.

Comment: Too much installation just for indenting automatically

Comment: @EmreSülün That is indeed a lot to install to indent automatically. On the other hand, indenting properly latex file is far from trivial (latexindent's documentation is over 100 pages!).

Comment: Yes, exactly. Indenting tex files is not trivial. To make it work for a variety of different users and preferences is a significant project

Comment: Log4Perl no longer required. See my answer

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks for the update. However, another module (I don't remember) was required which my answer helps install it as well the same way. Anyway, thanks for making latexindent to help this community.

Answer (score 38):

### UPDATE:

*Log4perl is **definitely** no longer required. See comments.*

### Original Answer

For others running into the same issue but on a Mac:

Install perl via `brew`:

```
brew install perl
```

Use `cpan` to install the necessary `perl` packages:

Open `cpan` and select `yes` if necessary to setup the config automatically:

```
cpan
```

Then install any packages mentioned in your error logs, you may need to install and retry several times to figure out all of the packages you need.

In my case these packages fixed the error messages:

```
install Log::Log4perl
install Log::Dispatch::File
install YAML::Tiny
install File::HomeDir
```

### Catalina Update

If the installation fails with an error message that sounds like a permissions issue, that may be due to security changes in Catalina. In that case, try forcing the installation:

```sh
cpan -fi \
  Log::Log4perl \
  Log::Dispatch::File \
  YAML::Tiny \
  File::HomeDir \
  Unicode::GCString
```

Comment: The question is for OS W10.

Comment: People searching for the same issue on a Mac (per my case) also end up on this page.

Comment: I also needed `install Unicode::GCString` Mac catalina and TeXLive 2019

Comment: I don't understand how to install `brew` without first installing perl. How do I do that?

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL `brew` is a separate package manager on the Mac. It is completely unrelated to Latex but allows you to install third-party packages (like `perl` in this case) that might be used by Latex. Google "homebrew" for installation instructions.

Comment: @songololo Thanks. I finally got everything working without `brew` after all (and wading through some atrociously written documentation).

Comment: I had to add sudo: sudo cpan -fi ....

Comment: ***to everyone*** Log4Perl no longer required

Comment: Not apparently, *definitely * :)

Comment: Ha, OK, updated.

Answer (score 3):

As of [Version 3.9](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/releases/tag/V3.9) the `Log4Perl` module is no longer loaded by `latexindent.pl`.

Details of the required perl modules are [documented](https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/appendices.html) and sample installations steps are given in [.travis.yml](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/blob/master/.travis.yml) and [appveyor.yml](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/blob/master/.appveyor.yml)

I sincerely hope that this eases installation and use of the tool. If you can help make `latexindent.pl` better, or have any questions, please visit https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl.

Answer (score 2):

## MacOS Big Sur

New problems arise for **Big Sur**. Here is my Fix.

(The solution assumed you've installed [homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation). )

### Step 1.  Install the perl & its package manager

```sh
brew install perl
brew install cpanm
```

### Step 2. Create symlink for `MacOSX10.14.sdk`

Install the missing packages directly will raise the build error:

> clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/**MacOSX10.14.sdk**' [-Wmissing-sysroot]

That's because:

> Apple decided to stop naming their SDKs with versions but rather name them MacOSX.sdk and include an alias with the version name for compatibility

So we create [symlink](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Symbolic_link) for this folder. (Difference between recent SDKs is minor)

```sh
> cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
> sudo ln -s MacOSX.sdk MacOSX10.14.sdk
```

### Step 3.  Install the missing packages

```sh
cpanm YAML::Tiny
cpanm File::HomeDir
cpanm Unicode::GCString
cpanm Log::Log4perl
cpanm Log::Dispatch
```

Comment: Log4Perl no longer required :)