# Adding entry .bib file breaks LaTeX Workshop in VS Code

Tags: bibtex, perl, latexindent

When I add an entry to my .bib file and save it, I get an error on compilation that reads:

> Formatting failed. Please refer to LaTeX Workshop Output for details.

Chasing the hint, I see in the LaTeX Workshop tab of the OUTPUT pane:

```
[10:55:52] LaTeX build process spawned. PID: 24624.
[10:55:52] Formatting with command latexindent -c,{folderName}/,{folderName}/__latexindent_temp.tex,-y=defaultIndent: '  '
[10:55:52] Parsed 151 bib entries from {folderName}/bibfile.bib.
[10:55:52] Formatting failed with exit code 2
[10:55:52] stderr: Can't locate File/HomeDir.pm in @INC (you may need to install the File::HomeDir module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.4 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/GetYamlSettings.pm line 22.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/GetYamlSettings.pm line 22.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/LogFile.pm line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/LogFile.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/Document.pm line 25.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/Document.pm line 25.
Compilation failed in require at /Library/TeX/texbin/latexindent line 27.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Library/TeX/texbin/latexindent line 27.

[10:55:52] Recipe of length 1 finished. PID: 24624.
```

I have `cpan` and `perl` installed in `/usr/bin/` (according to `which perl` and `which cpan`). I tried installing `File::HomeDir` but was not able to do so. Still, this error message is confusing, because the error **is not thrown** if I have not modified bibfile.bib this session. For example, the problem "goes away" if I save the bibfile, and restart VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was contained in here:

[latexindent: Can't locate Log/Log4perl.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Log::Log4perl module)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445521/latexindent-cant-locate-log-log4perl-pm-in-inc-you-may-need-to-install-the-l)

The reason why this post didn't initially work for me is that I was using Mac's default version of `perl` and `cpan`, 5.18, and that these are installed in a folder that isn't easily accessible to `cpan`. After I ran `brew install perl`, which installed 5.30 in `/usr/local/bin`, I was able to solve the problem as described in the above link.