# Struggling with Biber, can't figure out how to install the Perl packages

Tags: biber, perl

When I run Biber, with the command `biber filename`, it gives me this error (my emphasis):

> Can't locate **Biber.pm** in @INC (you may need to install the Biber module) (@INC contains: /home/christiank/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/christiank/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.32.0 /home/christiank/anaconda3/lib/5.32.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/christiank/anaconda3/lib/5.32.0 .) at /usr/bin/vendor_perl/biber line 17.

Initially `Log/Log4Perl.pm` was the offending package, but I was able to install it following the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445521/latexindent-cant-locate-log-log4perl-pm-in-inc-you-may-need-to-install-the-l).  But now I can't figure out how to install Biber.  I've tried just installing it with `sudo pacman -S biber`, and it installs... but I feel like I'm missing some Perl package.  Wondering if anyone knows whats up.

Edit: I've tried running `install Biber` in CPAN, but no luck.

Comment: The Biber binaries that are distributed via CTAN and are shipped in the "vanilla" versions of the big TeX distributions TeX live and MikTeX are self-contained and bundle all dependencies, so if you installed from those sources, this error should not be happening. Some linux distributions don't have the binary Biber in their repositories, but distribute a Perl script version, which may have additional dependencies, but in this case I'd expect the dependencies to be installed by the package manager. ...

Comment: ... Which OS are you using. How did you install your TeX system? How exactly did you install Biber?

Comment: There are at least two related issues at the Biber bug tracker: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/214, https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/313. The issue you are reporting usually seems to be connected to people trying to run a Biber built from source rather than the recommended binary.

Comment: Both perl as well as python use "pip" so when biber installation script tries to install perl programs it calls the python pip (see anaconda)... deactivate conda for the install.

Answer (score 2):

The same problem happened to me. It seems that biber is trying to use the perl inside your conda environment. I solved it by running `conda deactivate` and then `biber` worked fine for me.

Comment: This seems indeed to be the issue when trying to use (the system's) biber within a conda environment. If you do not really need perl, you can `conda uninstall perl`. This way biber works within conda. Unfortunately tex and conda do not work well together at the moment.

Comment: This did not fix the issue for me on KDE Neon.